# How can I add TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate only for one page in UITabBarController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, three20

Hi I have a tabbar controller which includes two pages A and B. Now I just want to add `TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate` to page A.

If I put the code:

```
- (id<TTTableViewDelegate>) createDelegate {
  TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate *delegate = [[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self];

  return [delegate autorelease];
}
```

Into `UITabBarController` then both A and B got refresh, so I put above code into A's view controller and call A's view controller in `UITabBarController` like this:

```
if (_page == APage) {
  AViewController *_aViewController = [[[AViewController alloc] init] autorelease];             

  self.dataSource = _aViewController.dataSource; 
  ...
}
```

But seems not work, page A still not get drag and refresh. So how can I get `TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate` only for page A in a `UITabBarController`?

This is `AViewController` init code:

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    self.variableHeightRows = YES;
    id<TTTableViewDataSource> ds = [APageDataSource dataSourceWithItems:nil];
    ds.model = CreateTabModelWithCurrentSettings();
    self.dataSource = ds;
  }

  return self;
}
```

How to let make page A get all `AViewController`'s properties? Like `AViewController`'s model, `dataSource`, something like that?

Comment: why do you assign the datasource into the tabbar controller? is there a reason for that?

Comment: Well, I tried assign datasource into AViewPageController but seems not work, I think maybe something wrong with the AViewController init, let me put AViewController init code on

Comment: Or, anyway I can assign the dragfresh to a specified page in tabbar controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AViewController should be a subclass of TTTableViewController